# Permanent Env variable not recognised

Tags: bash, gitlab, .profile

I have a script placed in /etc/profile.d/script.sh that on SSH connect checks if the user has the environment variables 'GIT_AUTHOR_NAME' and 'GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL' set in their ~/.profile file.

If not, it asks to enter these details. Problem I am having is that even though the Env variables exist, the script keeps asking to enter details. This is what /etc/profile.d/script.sh looks like:

```
if grep -Fxq "GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" /$PWD/.profile
then
    echo Git details already known > /dev/null
else
    echo "To make sure your commits are shown under your name, you have to enter your Git details once."
    read -p "Enter your Git author name: " gituser
    echo export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$gituser" >> /$PWD/.profile
    read -p "Enter your Git e-mail address: " gitemail
    echo export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$gitemail" >> /$PWD/.profile
    echo "Your git name "$gituser" and e-mail "$gitemail" are now saved as environment variables in your .profile file."
fi
```

Does this have anything to do with subshelling of some kind? I have tried various differations of checking whether the env variables are set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `-x` with grep; unless I'm mistaken, that

> *"Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line"*

(from [`man grep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)).

I suspect that it is instead the *beginning* of the line, perhaps with

```sh
if grep -q "^GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" /$PWD/.profile
```

or, if there is any `export`ing going on, a more expansive regex:

```sh
if grep -Eq "^[[:space:]]*(export)[[:space:]]*GIT_AUTHOR_NAME[[:space:]]*=" /$PWD/.profile
```

Comment: Your second solution works @r2evans. Amazing, thank you!

Comment: Do you know of a method to exclude root from this script? So that on SSH connect if root = don't run script / don't set env variables.

Comment: `[ $UID = 0 ] && exit`? (I'm assuming that this script is running as the user, not as root.) While I cannot imagine that not working, you can always filter on `$PWD` for root's homedir.